# creating a 2 column grid using Jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am creating an 2 column grid using jquery mobile. By default both the columns take 50% width. I want to customize in such a way that first column will take content size and the remaining space is allotted to column B. Any help as how this can be achieved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this easily with a TABLE:

```
<table class="tblcontainer">
    <tr>
        <td class="fluidCell"><input type="search" name="search" id="txt" placeholder="Search something" /></td>
        <td class="fixedCell" ><a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline">Go</a></td>
    </tr>                        
</table>

.tblcontainer {
    width: 100%;
}
.tblcontainer .fixedCell {
    width: 1%;
    padding-left: 8px;    
}
```

> Working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/x97s3752/7/)**